# Y-axis not properly sorted matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm attempting to plot a temperature vs date graph with Matplotlib in Python3. The dates are in increasing order along the x-axis, but the y-axis is not set up from smallest to largest. Matplotlib defines the range seemingly correctly, but then the y-axis doesn't begin at the smallest value and the order becomes more incorrect at the top of the plot as seen here: [y-axis view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtV6.png)

The code I'm using to plot is below. The data comes from a dictionary with four keys (ie: US...) that each have four lists as their values. The first contains the dates, the second a maximum temp, then min temp, then average.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
...
pyplot.figure(figsize = (250, 20))
pyplot.plot(\
station_dict['USW00012839'][0], station_dict['USW00012839'][1], 'b-', \
station_dict['USC00081306'][0], station_dict['USC00081306'][1], 'b-', \
station_dict['USW00092811'][0], station_dict['USW00092811'][1], 'b-', \
station_dict['USC00085667'][0], station_dict['USC00085667'][1], 'b-', \
station_dict['USW00012839'][0], station_dict['USW00012839'][2], 'g-', \
station_dict['USC00081306'][0], station_dict['USC00081306'][2], 'g-', \
station_dict['USW00092811'][0], station_dict['USW00092811'][2], 'g-', \
station_dict['USC00085667'][0], station_dict['USC00085667'][2], 'g-', \
station_dict['USW00012839'][0], station_dict['USW00012839'][3], 'r-', \
station_dict['USC00081306'][0], station_dict['USC00081306'][3], 'r-', \
station_dict['USW00092811'][0], station_dict['USW00092811'][3], 'r-', \
station_dict['USC00085667'][0], station_dict['USC00085667'][3], 'r-' \
)
pyplot.title('Miami Temperature from August 2015 to December 2017\n', \
size = 'x-large', weight = 'bold')
pyplot.ylabel('Temperature (Fahrenheit)', style = 'italic')
pyplot.xlabel('Date', style = 'italic')
pyplot.xticks(rotation = 'vertical')
pyplot.show()
```

The whole plot can be seen here: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JeFP.jpg)

The whole scripts can be found here: [parseNCEI.py](https://github.com/underasail/other/blob/master/parseNCEI.py)
though the path would need to be edited to wherever the below file is.

And the file the data is coming from can be found here: [1166240.csv](https://github.com/underasail/other/blob/master/1166240.csv)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check that your y data are not strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DavidG suggested, I was checking my data and converted the y values from strings to integers and this solved the issue.

Comment: it seems it interprets strings as different values